# Else if statement with 3 or more conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have been trying for a long time and cant seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong. The first too conditions seem to work but the third fails.

```
function spriteAI1() {

                if (c2Sprite.position.x >= 30 && c2Sprite.position.x <= 450) { 
                c2Sprite.translateX( -10 );
                } else if (c2Sprite.position.x <= 30 && c2Sprite.position.x >= -450) {
                c2Sprite.translateX( 10 );
                } else if (c2Sprite.position.z = 30 && c2Sprite.position.x = 30) { 
                c2Sprite.remove;
                c2Sprite.clone;
                }
                else{}
            }   

            function spriteAI2() {

                if (c2Sprite.position.z >= 30 && c2Sprite.position.z <= 350) { 
                c2Sprite.translateZ( -10 );
                } else if (c2Sprite.position.z <= -30 && c2Sprite.position.z >= -350) {
                c2Sprite.translateZ( 10 );  
                } else if (c2Sprite.position.x = 30 && c2Sprite.position.z = 30) { 
                c2Sprite.remove;
                c2Sprite.clone;
                }
                else{}
            }
```

I'm getting an error on the line

```
else if (c2Sprite.position.x = 30 && c2Sprite.position.z = 30)
```

the error says `invalid left hand in assignment`. But the other function has basically the same line and doesn't generate a error.

Comment: You want `==` (comparison) not `=` (assignment, which is also a valid expression)

Comment: Is that a runtime exception or a syntax error?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the help. That corrected the error I had. After reworking the code a bit and adding console.log I can see that both position x and z are hitting 30 but the last condition is still not firing. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was runtime or syntax sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems in your code.

First, comparison is done using `==` (double equal signs), not a single one (that's assigning a value). That's probably the source of your problem.

In second place, your last two conditions match a common group of values (they are **intersected**), in the case when `c2Sprite.position.x` equals 30, it will enter the second "if". It will match the condition for the third one, but it will not run it.

Make sure you always define well-separated groups of conditions (unless that's the behavior that you want).

Just to make it clear:

```
if (x >= 30) {
    /* this matches 30 and above */
}
else if (x == 30) {
    /* this won't execute on x == 30, because it entered the first "if" */
}
```

You should have done this:

```
if (x > 30) {
    /* this matches numbers strictly greater than 30, i.e. 31, 32, 33... */
}
else if (x == 30) {
    /* this will match x == 30 */
}
else {
    /* any other value for x */
}
```

Comment: Awesome and thanks for the help. I have reworked the code but still cant get it to trigger the third condition.

Comment: I would do this: `if (c2Sprite.position.z > 30 && c2Sprite.position.z <= 350) /* ... */ } else if (c2Sprite.position.z < -30 && c2Sprite.position.z >= -350) { /* ... */ } else if (c2Sprite.position.x == 30 && c2Sprite.position.z == 30) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by there. Sorry I'm new to using forms. Is there some thing i'm not seeing.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed the intro key by mistake. Look at it now. Btw, the first function has the same problem, do a strict `x > 30` and `x < 30` in the first two conditions, otherwise the third one will never be executed.

Comment: Thanks. Getting rid of that last else fixed the issue. The log is now displaying the indented message. It's still not removing the sprite but I guess i must be using the wrong three.js command or some thing. Again thanks for the help that use == not = thing was killing me. Your a life saver.